# T-SQL like not working like expected - returning LESS hits than the same query using =

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have two rows in a table containing the SAME information in the 'Name' column (nvarchar(50), not null).

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = 'ColumnValue'
```

returns **both** rows

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE 'ColumnValue'
```

returns **only one** row

Does any one have any idea what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: is your columns value has trailing space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely due to trailing spaces. Performing an `=` operation excludes trailing space but `LIKE` doesn't.

For example, this will return a match:

```
SELECT 'match' WHERE 'fred' = 'fred   '
```

But this won't:

```
SELECT 'match' WHERE 'fred' LIKE 'fred   '
```

Comment: You are a rockstar!  I have no idea how the spaces entered the database, but after doing the following   update TableName set ColumnName = ltrim(rtrim(ColumnName)) where ColumnName = 'ColumnValue' seems to have solved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Good to know about this

Comment: The behaviour is not optional. ANSI padding doesn't affect this.

Answer (score 1):

I always use % when using like

change your like statement to

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%ColumnValue%'
```

using the exact column value is always better but there are times that you dont remember the exact string to its just too long.